# Does Fubini's theorem imply $\int_X (\int _Y f _x d \lambda )d \mu=\int _X d \mu \int _Yf(x,y) d \lambda$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need some help with intepretating the result of Fubini's theorem.

define $ \phi (x) =\int_Y f _x d \lambda $ and $ \psi (y)= \int _X f _y d \mu$

According to Rudin, Fubinis theorem tells us that $\int_X \phi d \mu =\int f d ( \mu \times \lambda )= \int _Y \psi d \lambda$

Under sufficient conditions for Fubinis theorem to apply.

---

Now how does it follow that $\int_X (\int _Y f _x d \lambda )d \mu=\int _X d \mu \int _Yf(x,y) d \lambda$

this might be obvious but does the first conclusion imply the second equality, since as I see it  it only says that the left side of the last equation equals the integral of $f(x,y) $ with respect to the product measure over $X \times Y $.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The equality you as asking about just follows by the definition of $f_x$ and by a change of notation. The notation $\int_X d\mu \int_Y f(x,y) d\lambda$ just means $\int_X \int_Y f(x,y) d\lambda d\mu = \int_X \int_Y f_x d\lambda d\mu$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: But $\int _X d \mu \int _Y f(x,y) d \lambda$ says to me that we can multiply the tw integrals. Wheras the left side of the last equation in my question says that we get a function $\phi (x) $ which we then integrate over $X $.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean a product. It's just a confusing notation for iterated integrals. $\int_X\,d\mu \int_Y f(x,y)\,d\lambda$ means $$\int_X \left(\int_Y f(x,y)\,d\lambda\right)\,d\mu$$ although it looks differently.

Comment: And some would even go so far as to write $$\int_X\,d\mu \int_Y\,d\lambda\, f.$$ (_shivers in fear_)

Comment: Ok, that answers my confusion. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder how much time is 'wasted' when convention boundaries are crossed like this...